# What does a sequence of comparison operations in c represent/do?

Tags: c

I have been playing around with what would be considered valid C syntax and what wouldn't,
I tried `1<2<1`, and to my surprise, it is a valid C syntax.  Does anyone know what that would do or represent ?

I tried figuring it out by testing the value this kind of expressions take and changing the integer values but found no pattern.

Comment: you get the result of `true < 1`

Comment: Always chain comparisons with `&&` and `||` and use parentheses as necessary to disambiguate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, when using a relational operator such as `<`, the result will always be `1` if the condition is true, or `0` if the condition is false.

Due to the [rules on operator precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the expression

```
1<2<1
```

is equivalent to:

```
(1<2)<1
```

The sub-expression `(1<2)` is true, so it will evaluate to `1`, so the entire expression is equivalent to:

```
1<1
```

Since this expression is false, it will evaluate to `0`.

Therefore, writing `1<2<1` is equivalent to writing `0`.

Comment: Note also that in C, `<` has *different* precedence than `==`, unlike languages that support math-style chaining.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the *associativity* of the `<` operator, the expression `1 < 2 < 1` is the same as `(1 < 2) < 1`.

So you're checking if the boolean result of `1 < 2` is less than `1`. And the result of `1 < 2` is `true` which will be converted to the integer value `1` (`false` would become `0`).

In other words, `1 < 2 < 1` is transformed into `1 < 1` which is `false`.

Comment: Which dangerously looks right. Consider `-4 < -3 < -2`. On face value, not knowing how C works, that's true. But while `-4` is less than `-3`, that evaluates to true, which is greater than `-2`.